Jira JQL gitBranch conditions
I have gitBranch customer field.

I need to create some filters .
Filter for ticket in dev,main,stage branches.
The filter like

gitBranch = "main"
gitBranch IN("main")

is working fine.
But for dev and stage filters i need some additinial conditions.
The dev tickets filter should be like
gitBranch = "dev" AND NOT (gitBranch  = "stage")

But all filters with NOT are failed for me.
I have test ticket for that which in ws-640 branch and dev branch

Also i am dont even able write conditions like
not in

or !=


